# Removing an added provider in Jersey

Tags: jersey, provider, dropwizard

I am using com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Environment addProvider method to register providers in Jersey.I have a custom provider too which does a task similar to Dropwizards own MessageBodyWriterProvider.

Jersey seems to select the inbuilt MessageBodyWriter instead of my custom one.So I figured that if I remove the inbuild provider which is registered and register my own it will work properly.

Is there a way to remove the already added provider with the class name or other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
environment.getJerseyResourceConfig().getSingletons()
```

returns a mutable `Set<Object>` of all the resources and providers registered with Jersey. A simple iteration over this with an `instanceOf` check should be enough.

The related method `getProviderSingletons` won't work because it is returning a new set. And removing from that set won't remove from the original.

Comment: This is no [longer true](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/cf432faf9b1e6a02065e3efccfa1ef2087583d8a/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.java#L788) - 

`@Override
public final Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    if (cachedSingletonsView == null) {
        cachedSingletons = _getSingletons();
        cachedSingletonsView = Collections.unmodifiableSet(cachedSingletons == null ? new HashSet<>() : cachedSingletons);
    }

    return cachedSingletonsView;
}`